# Cloudant query to return records where 2 fields are equal

Tags: swift, cloudant

I can search for specific values for fields. How can I search for fields equal to other fields?  For example,

I have `docId` and `parentDocId`; how do I search for records that have `docId == parentDocId`?

query to search for specific id which equals "123":

```
let query = ["parentDocId": ["$eq":"123"]]
let result = datastore.find(query, skip: 0, limit: 0, fields: nil, sort: nil)
```

I would like to search where parentDocId == docId.

Any ideas?

p.s. I am using Swift

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use Cloudant Query. Assuming your docs have the following structure

```
{
 "_id": "2b7946de457b6fc9af3e3d29faa3fcba",
 "_rev": "3-088f847ef010504e7a5beb0c821d72ea",
 "parentDocId": "2b7946de457b6fc9af3e3d29faa3fcba",
 ...
}
```

you can create [a view](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/creating_views.html) like this

```
PUT https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$HOST/$DATABASE/_design/demo HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

 {
  "views": {
  "parent_child": {
   "map": "function (doc) {\n  if(doc._id === doc.parentDocId) {\n    emit(doc._id, 1);\n  }\n}"
   }
  }
 }
```

and query it:

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$HOST/$DATABASE/_design/demo/_view/parent_child HTTP/1.1
```

All client libraries should support views since they are a fundamental concept in CouchDB/Cloudant. I'm not familiar with Swift but the library documentation should identify the appropriate method you need to invoke to make a call that's equivalent to the general HTTP one I listed.

Comment: Hmm. The only thing is that I am currently using it in offline first mode. There is no internet, and no cloud. Can I still create views in offline mode? I'll give it a try.

Comment: If you have a local pouchdb for your offline first setup, you can create views there too, yes.